# How to render queryset in django template

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, django-queryset

Hi Im using this code for rendering

```
def ShowContent(dic, htmlpage):
    plantilla = get_template(htmlpage)
    c = Context(dic)
    renderizado = plantilla.render(c)
    return HttpResponse(renderizado)
```

and I wanna represent this Query, so I use 'AllQuery' dict for 'todas.html'.

```
def ShowAll(request):
    AllQuery = Actividad.objects.all().order_by('fecha')
    print AllQuery
    return ShowContent(AllQuery, 'todas.html')
```

I don't know how to represent it in my template

```
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>
```

Actividad from models.py

```
 class Actividad(models.Model):
    id_evento = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo_evento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gratis = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    hora = models.TimeField()
    largo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=128)
```

any idea? I think its easy but I'm not gettin it. I'm trying this:

```
                            {% for i in AllQuery %}
                                { AllQuery.i.titulo }
                            {% endfor %}
```

from views, I can access doing

```
def ShowAll(request):
    AllQuery = Actividad.objects.all().order_by('fecha')
    print AllQuery[0].titulo
```

Comment: This should work, {% for i in AllQuery %}                                 {{ i.titulo }}                             {% endfor %}

Comment: it doesn't, I've tried :'( help?

Comment: I think that the queryset, returns me a list, not a dict. I mean, a list of "Actividad" objects, Actividad is a dict

Comment: Why do you persist with this pointless ShowContent function? The whole thing could be replaced by a call to `django.shortcuts.render`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a generic list view, this will make your life a lot easier and save some time.

```
class ListView(generic.ListView)
    model=Actividad
    template_name='todas.html'
```

and then in your template you can display the list like so

```
{% for i in object_list %}
    {{ i.titulo }}
{% endfor %}
```